# finding loop invariant for two nested while loops java

Tags: java, nested-loops, invariants, loop-invariant

I'm a bit familiar with invariant and I can more or less find it for a small loops.
I am so confused when solving invariant for the following pseudo-code for java.
can anyone help please:

```
Input: an array A
i <- length(A)
# outer invariant
while i != 0 do
  k <- i
  j <- i - 1
  # inner invariant
  while j != 0 do
    if A[j] > A[k] then
      k <- j
    j <- j - 1
    # inner invariant
  swap(A, i, k)
  i <- i - 1
# outer invariant
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can u help me with this too? this is confusing me

Answer (score 1):

You should work out the invariants of nested loops starting with the inner one:

```
while (j != 0) {
    if (A[j] > A[k]) {
        k = j;
    }
    j--;
}
```

you can observe that

```
A[k] >= A[x], for any (j < x) && (x <= i)
```

At the end of the loop, `j == 0`, so using [Hoare Tripple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) for the `while` loop you can state that at the end of the inner loop

```
A[k] >= A[x], for any (0 < x <= i)
```

This is another way of saying that `A[k]` is `MAX(A[0:i])`.

Now you can proceed with the outer loop: since `i` proceeds from `A.length` down to zero, the invariant would be

```
A[y] < A[x], for any (y >= i) for any (y < x <= Length(A))
```

Using Hoare Trippe once again, you derive that upon exiting the outer loop the array `A` is sorted in ascending order:

```
A[y] < A[x], for any (y >= 0) for any (y < x <= Length(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment can be reduced and formatted like the following (are you used to C language syntax?):

```
for ( i = n; i > 0 ; i -- ) {
    for ( j = i - 1 ; j > 0 ; j -- ) {
        // Constant time instructions here symbolized by c
    }
}
```

Passing to Sigma Notation won't be too cumbersome from the above fragment:

[image]